# Does node.js have built-in support for UDP(datagams)?

Tags: node.js, udp

I'm confused as to how to install the proper UDP package in node.js.

When I try

```
npm install dgram
```

I get an error message saying package not available.

So is UDP support 'builtin' to the default node.js install ?

Comment: If it is listed in [`Node's API docs`](http://nodejs.org/api/) then it is builtin. So in this case, yes `dgram` is always available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dgram` is built into the API of node. Just require away.

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
```

[Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html).